# Close dialog changes have now made going back hard to spot

Tags: bug, design, close-dialog

The old tree at the top of the dialogue was large and a different colour indicating it was clickable.

[image]

Now it is small, low contrast and all the same colour so it is hard to even know it is clickable so you can go back.

[image]

It also misses the current pages title now which makes it harder again to give that colour change to note the other page headings are clickable.

For what it's worth it wasn't until I was writing this question that I even noticed that there is now a "back" link at the bottom.

Comment: Please move or copy this to https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/346638/256282